# cURL DELETE in Java

Tags: java, apache, url, curl, xmlhttprequest

Like the title says, I'm trying to write the following curl `DELETE` command in **Java**.

```
curl -X DELETE -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" http://10.84.14.2:8082/virtual-network/47a91732-629b-4cbe-9aa5-45ba4d7b0e99
```

My understanding is that you have to format the `DELETE` request inside of a `POST`. Below is my working code for a `GET` call.

```
URL dc0ContrailUrl2 = new URL("http://10.10.10.120:8082/network-policy/363bf699-6417-486e-9791-d5aaf873d9bb");
    URLConnection dcConn2 = dc0ContrailUrl2.openConnection();
    dcConn2.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    BufferedReader in2 = newBufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(dcConn2.getInputStream()));

    String inputLine2;

while ((inputLine2 = in2.readLine()) != null){ //while response is not null, assign response to inputLine and print inputLine
        System.out.println(inputLine2); 
}
        in2.close();
```

When I looked around for how to approach a `DELETE` request, I ended up with the following:

```
URL url3 = new URL("http://10.10.10.120:8082/network-policy/363bf699-6417-486e-9791-d5aaf873d9bb");
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection3 = (HttpURLConnection) url3.openConnection();
        httpConnection3.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConnection3.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json" );
        httpConnection3.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
```

At this point I've gone so far down the google rabbit hole that I'm certain the solution is very simple and is just a matter of changing some syntax/method calls. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Note:** I am able to get the `DELETE` call to work using Postman(chrome app) by simply entering the URL `http://10.10.10.120:8082/network-policy/363bf699-6417-486e-9791-d5aaf873d9bb`, and switching the drop down menu to `DELETE`, so I know my URL isn't the issue.

Comment: Use an external library as @morgano suggested. I personally recommend [UniRest](http://unirest.io/) if you're going to work with RESTful services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `HttpURLConnection` directly, try with a library like the [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/index.html) from the [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/), an example of how you can use it with your delete command:

```
void sendDelete() throws IOException {
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

    // create DELETE REQUEST
    HttpDelete httpDelete = new HttpDelete(
        "http://10.84.14.2:8082/virtual-network/47a91732-629b-4cbe-9aa5-45ba4d7b0e99");

    // add header "content-type"
    httpDelete.addHeader(new BasicHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"));

    // send request
    CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpDelete);

    // close response (ideally inside a finally clause in a try/catch)
    response1.close();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding is that you have to format the `DELETE` request inside of a `POST`.

That is incorrect.  The Curl command you posted performs a 'DELETE' request, and in this sense POST and DELETE (and GET) are alternative HTTP request "methods".  There might be web services that accept some kind of delete command in the form of a POST and/or GET request, but that's not what Curl is doing.  (It's also not what Postman is doing when you select the 'DELETE' request method.)

Your code is actually pretty much right.  It's not useful to specify that you're going to do output (because you're not), nor, therefore, to specify a Content-type (because the request will have no content), but it's probably not harmful to do so.  You could even `setDoInput(false)` on the connection, since you wouldn't normally expect the server to send any content in its response, but leaving that out should be ok, too.

The main thing you're missing is a call to the connection's `connect()` method.  You don't need that in your "GET" example because reading the connection's input stream causes it to connect automatically.

Comment: I'm not sure if you should have `setDoInput(true)` since the server won't return a response for DELETE requests.

Comment: You certainly don't need `setDoInput(true)` if you're not going to read the connection's input stream.  I think it's ok to specify it, though.  If the server behaves typically then the stream will just be empty.